# Accessing RouteData in ServiceStack's AuthUserSession

Tags: servicestack

I would like to make a secondary check on the user's permissions.
My controllers are decorated with the `[RequiredPermission("ExamplePermission")]`, that by the way corresponds to the controller name.

Rather than only checking if the `ExamplePermission` string is contained in the `Session.Permissions` list, I would like to add a check on the RouteData parameters.

Can I access such object in the method `HasPermission`?

```
    public override bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
        //checking routedata's parameters
        return base.HasPermission(permission);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging with the console output I actually managed to reach the RouteData values in this way:

```
    public override bool HasPermission(string permission)
    {
            bool hasPermission = base.HasPermission(permission);
            var routeValues = ((System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper)(((ServiceStack.Host.AspNet.AspNetRequest)(HostContext.GetCurrentRequest())).HttpRequest)).RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
            var idObj = routeValues["Id"];

            if (idObj != null)
            {
                int id;
                if(int.TryParse((string)idObj, out id))
                {
                    [...]
                }
            }
            return hasPermission;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to access the current Route from inside the `AuthUserSession` but you can add a check in a Global Request Filter instead which lets you access the Service and Request Type, metadata about your Service and your Users Session, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    var requestType = dto.GetType();
    var serviceType = HostContext.Metadata.GetServiceTypeByRequest(requestType);
    var operation = HostContext.Metadata.GetOperation(requestType);

    //operation.RequiredPermissions
    //operation.RequiresAnyPermission
    //...

    var userSession = req.GetSession();
    //userSession.HasPermission(...)
    //...
});
```